ADO flaky test build shows failed
I am working on managing flaky tests in my project. I am using ADO flaky test feature.
I am seeing build is marked as failed even though I marked test as flaky.
Here my test pass report shows all passed but build failed.
How will we ensure if a failed test is flaky, pipeline build won't fail?

This is my test management configuration


I can reproduce the same issue that the subsequent builds are still gets failed due to the failed test that has been marked as Flaky in the previous build, even if the option "Flaky tests included in test pass percentage" has been unchecked on "Project Settings" > "Test management" page.

Looks like, there is a problem on Azure Pipelines that the build with failed flaky test cannot correctly show the state based on the Test management settings.
I recommend you try to open a ticket on Developer Community to report this issue, if the support engineer who handle your ticket also can reproduce the issue, they can help to report the issue to the appropriate product team for further investigation and fixing.


Thanks reported issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ADO-has-flaky-test-marked-but-subsequent/10639629

@hasan.in, I noticed your ticket has been duplicated to another ticket that reports the same issue, and that ticket has been reported to the product team by the support engineer. You can keep following that ticket and add your comments on it.
